# Get list for duplicates on an other list python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I need help to get a list from an other :

input :

```
[[1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]]
```

output wanted :

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I tried to use enumerate but I fail, any suggestion ?

Edit : Every time I meet a new element in the list, I associate this new element with a number (start from 0 and +1 every new element) and if I recognize it later I put the same number, so [1,1] --> 0 because is the first element we met and [2,2] --> 1 etc...

Okay I found a solution :

- One more thing before, my example is bad because I can have [1,2] in element of the list for input
- the solution I found is

```
line = [[1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]]
p = []
line_not = []
k = 0
for i in range (len(line)):
    if line[i] in line[:i]:
        p.append(line_not[:k].index(line[i]))
    else:
        p.append(k)
        line_not.append(line[i])
        k+=1
```

the output is :

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 4]
```

If u have a better solution, tell me !

Comment: Could you explain the intent more clearly?
What exactly should the output be?

Comment: What is the logic behind the expected output?

Comment: Every time I meet a new element in the liste, I associate this new element with a number and if I recongnize it later I put the same number, so [1,1] --> 0 because is the first element we met and [2,2] -- > 1 ...

Comment: You might want to use example data where the numbers aren't in ascending order; without the explanation of "every time I meet a new element" the natural assumption is that you just want to subtract 1 from each number.  :)

Answer (score 1):

try to make a map, this works:

inp=[[1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]]
out = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]

```
mymap={inp[0][0]:0}
output = [0]
k_count=1
for i in inp[1:]:
  if i[0] in mymap.keys():
    output.append(mymap[i[0]])
  else:
    mymap[i[0]] = k_count
    output.append(mymap[i[0]])
    k_count+=1
```

and then `output == [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

First build a dictionary that does the assocation of each unique element with a number:

```
>>> x = [[1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]]
>>> d = {}
>>> for [i, _] in x:
...     if i not in d:
...         d[i] = len(d)
...
```

and then you can easily build your output list by doing lookups in that dictionary:

```
>>> [d[i] for [i, _] in x]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

this would work in your current example, but it is not a comprehensive solution. Without context its hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, so use with care:

```
import numpy as np
inp = [[1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]]
out = np.array([i[0] for i in inp]) - 1
print(out)  # result: [0 0 1 0 0 1 2 3]
```